# Knapsack of mixture with constraints

Tags: optimization, evolutionary-algorithms, heuristics

I'm trying to find the optimized mixture for a specific set of substances. Each of those substances have characteristics that I want to optimize in the mixture (some characteristics I want to minimize and others I want to maximize). But I can't have more than 50% (random value that will be set on running time) of one of those substances in the mixture.

I thought about using Genetic Algorithm, but I'm not sure it's the best approach for this problem. Do you have any suggestions?

Edit: it doesn't need to be a evolutionary algorithm.

Comment: Can you calculate a single value that reflects the optimization? If so some sort of simplex would work.

Comment: @MaxW I'll try the simplex. Thanks, I think that will do.